# Asking the user for minutes then telling them what it is in hours

Tags: python, time

Ask the user for a number of minutes. Tell them how long that is in hours. I am kinda new to python and still trying to figure out some of the basics but no matter what I try nothing works so please help.

Comment: Try and divide the minutes value by 60?

Comment: Can you share one of the things you've tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic steps:

```
# prompt for input and convert from str to int
minutes = int(input("minutes:" ))
# minutes: 135

# do the math
hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
# short-hand for
# hours = minutes // 60
# minutes = minutes % 60

# produce output of some kind
print(f"{hours}:{minutes}h")
# 2:15h
```

Docs on some utils:

- [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod)
- [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)
- [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)
- [output formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting)